# start a windows service using a webservice in php

Tags: php, android, web-services, windows-services

I was trying to start or stop a windows service from Android Device. For this i found using webservice would be more efficient way.

So i planned to create web service using php. From `php5.3` this can be achieved by using `win32_query_service_status`.But my server is with `php4`. So is there any other way to start or stop windows services using PHP

Comment: php4 is extremely old, cant you update it?

Comment: Can you just issue a `NET START` command?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: there are already several pre-existing modules were there, using some deprecated and removed function.so it is nearly impossible for me to change all modules.

Comment: @David i want to do it via a webservice

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can [issue system commands to the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), you can control the services using their [command-line interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564(v=ws.10).aspx).  Something like:

```
exec('NET START ServiceName');
```

Comment: was this `exec()` using secured connection to PC ?

Comment: @user2979046 The call from PHP to your own computer should be OK as long as you can guarantee that no bad values could be passed to it and that only people with proper authorization can invoke the call to `exec()`. Basically worry about _everything around_ `exec()` rather than about the inner workings of `exec()` itself.

Comment: @user2979046: What do you mean?  `exec()` simply invokes a command to the host's command-line shell.  It's as secure as any other PHP code executing in that context.  (Which means the user context under which the PHP application runs will need permission to invoke this command, of course.)  The security of the application being launched (in this case a Windows Service) is outside the scope of the PHP code.

Comment: The call will be going to other computers,so how should i connect web service and the PC ?

Comment: @user2979046: It's not clear what your setup is then.  Is the PHP application not on the host with the Windows Service?  In that case, how do you normally maintain those services from that host?  You could perhaps use the service console on the command line, something like: `SC \\HostName START ServiceName`

Comment: I am sorry, i should have explained full scenario.i will edit my question

Comment: @user2979046: That doesn't change anything about the potential solution.  The PHP web application would still need to issue commands to the Windows Service host in some way.  If there's no existing library you can use for that, then command-line usage is pretty much the way to go.

Comment: if the php web app is running a desktop the there is no problem of connection issue, but it will run on Android device,so i should connect Android device to PC, right ?

Comment: @user2979046: The *PHP code* is running on the Android device?  That's new information.  You probably want a service running on a *Windows host* to be the controller for the Windows Services (local or remote).  Then your device would simply issue commands to *that* service.  Managing Windows services from a non-Windows host sounds like a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: yes the php code will be running on host, now i need to connect that host to any PC in which i need to start or stop services